# Same Layout, Different Display on Phones

Tags: android

I am testing my application on a Nexus 6, and a Motorola G second generation. I have a layout that has a mix of cardviews and recyclerviews. One recyclerview in particular loads data from the background from a lorem ipsum generator and is supposed to display 10 reslults. On the Motorola G, it displays fine, but on the Nexus 6 instead of 10 results correctly it only displays one, On the left is the nexus 6, and on the right is the Motorola which displays everything correctly:

[image]

Here is the layout that is used for both phones:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewsFragments.FeedsFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        tools:context=".NewsFragments.FeedsFragment">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>




</ScrollView>
```

I am confused as to why one phone would scroll and the other doesn't considering it is the same information, as well as the same layout file being displayed the only difference being the size of the phone.

Any help in how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: I want these screens to have the same layout, they should be able to display the same information, everything in these layouts match up perfectly except for the recyclerview. I know how to create different layouts for different phones, is that the issue?

Comment: The layout design might need to vary from one size to another screen size. Please check the link above.

Comment: i had exactly your problem specially in Motorola phones .

Comment: I have two different phones that display the information correctly, dispite the different sizes, but I compared it to the Nexus 6 and the nexus 6 doesn't display it correctly

Comment: @Aaron Please add screenshots of all the devices mentioned.

Comment: There isn't anything different about the contents being displayed there are two devices that show the same content, with API level 27 and API level 22, and the Nexus 6 not displaying the correct information with API level 25.

Comment: The two phones that work have drastically different sizes and api levels and they work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        tools:context=".NewsFragments.FeedsFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/new_post_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cow_img"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="start|top"
                    android:hint="share a status update"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="116dp"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                    android:entries="@array/post_preferences"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton2"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="84dp"
                    android:layout_height="43dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:text="Post"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spinner"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.526" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="109dp" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:padding="10dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.CardView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"-->
        <!--app:cardElevation="4dp"-->
        <!--app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">-->

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <!--</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-->
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

What made it work was swapping the ScrollView, for a Nested ScrollView.

Comment: But there is only one child inside nestedscrollview.